# Remove the label and show only value in tooltips of a bar chart

Tags: jquery, charts, chart.js

I am using [**ChartJS**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) library to create charts. In the tooltip, I am showing the data value from the dataset I created. It works in case if the chart type is *doughnut*. Otherwise it doesn't work in case or *bar* or *horizontalbar* charts.

Whatever I do it shows the data with the labels.

**[Working JSFiddle of Doughnut Chart with data in tooltip](https://jsfiddle.net/suhaibjanjua/1ah2w2ug/)**.

[image: Doughnut Chart]

---

**[Working JSFiddle of Bar Chart with label + data in tooltip](https://jsfiddle.net/suhaibjanjua/or6b8j2m/133/)**.

[image: Bar Chart]

All I want to do is to remove the label shown in the tooltips of the bar chart.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [
      "Men",
      "Women",
      "Unknown"
    ],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Men',
        data: [60, 40, 20],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(158, 216, 202, 0.75)',
          'rgba(255, 150, 162, 0.75)',
          'rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.75)'
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'Women',
        data: [40, 70, 10],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(158, 216, 202, 0.5)',
          'rgba(255, 150, 162, 0.5)',
          'rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.5)'
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'Unknown',
        data: [33, 33, 34],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(158, 216, 202, 0.25)',
          'rgba(255, 150, 162, 0.25)',
          'rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.25)'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var datasetLabel = '';
          var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
          return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: for a simple solution you can also just use titleFontSize: 0, in your tooltips config.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just use the `title` option with an empty value. Like this:

```
callbacks: {
        title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
          return '';
        },
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var datasetLabel = '';
          var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
          return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
        }
      }
```

see [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/or6b8j2m/2/)

Answer (score 1):

this is how to get it done

```
tooltip: {
    enabled: true,
    displayColors:false,
    callbacks: {
        label:(tooltipItem)=>{
            return tooltipItem.parsed;
        },
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for the newest version of ChartJS 3.8.0:

```
 tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          title: function (tooltipItem) {
            return '';
          },
          label: function (tooltipItem) {
            var tooltipText = '';
            if (tooltipItem.dataset.data[tooltipItem.dataIndex] != null)
              tooltipText = tooltipItem.dataset.data[tooltipItem.dataIndex]!.toString();
            return tooltipText;
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to **pumpkinzzz**'s answer, if you want to display **ONLY** the label name, this is the approach you would follow. Leave the title empty, and return your string to the `label` property. This is because the Tooltip's label color is defined under that property.

Although this may look unnecessary, if your labels include chart data (all under one string), then by default the tooltip displays the data twice. If you're looking to avoid this, then the code below may help.

```
title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
  return '';
},
label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
  return data.labels[tooltipItem.index].toString(); //Some IDEs throw an error if you don't cast to a string
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For latest Version Of Chart.js (3.6.0)

```
plugins: {
    tooltip: {
        yAlign: 'top',
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem) {                                
                return tooltipItem.dataset.data;
            }
        }
    },
}
```