# Chart.js: Thousand Separator and Tittle ind the Middle of the Doughnut

Tags: chart.js

I have searched a lot and included a thousand separator in tooltips. But I would like to make it work everywhere there is text. Where I live we use "." to separate thousands and "," for decimal.

I didn't find a simple way to put the title in the middle of the doughnut.

This is what I have:

```js
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#7792b1';

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var dataset = [{
  label: 'Volume de Operações',
  data: [254000.87, 355000.57],
  backgroundColor: ['#4bb8df', '#6290df']
}]
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['CALL', 'PUT'],
    datasets: dataset
  },

  options: {
    rotation: 1 * Math.PI,
    circumference: 1 * Math.PI,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    cutoutPercentage: 60,
    plugins: {
      labels: [{
        render: 'label',
        arc: true,
        fontStyle: 'bold',
        position: 'outside'
      }, {
        render: 'percentage',
        fontColor: '#ffffff',
        precision: 1
      }],
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      fontSize: 15,
      text: [
        dataset.reduce((t, d) => t + d.data.reduce((a, b) => a + b), 0),
        'Volume Total'
      ],
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var dataLabel = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
          var value = ': ' + data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index].toLocaleString();
          if (Chart.helpers.isArray(dataLabel)) {
            dataLabel = dataLabel.slice();
            dataLabel[0] += value;
          } else {
            dataLabel += value;
          }
          return dataLabel;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart" style="max-width: 450px"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels/src/chartjs-plugin-labels.js"></script>
```

In short:

- Global thousand separator: (.)
- Title in the middle of doughnut
- Tooltip without label: Only value

Comment: Could you please improve the first paragraph a bit?. What you mean exactly with "I'd like to make it global: to title too." In the meantime here a few resources for [how to use dots as thousand separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800226/chart-js-add-commas-to-tooltip-and-y-axis), and [showing only values on tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294179/remove-the-label-and-show-only-value-in-tooltips-of-a-bar-chart). About the title [there is no such functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54396656/chart-js-how-can-i-align-the-legend-and-the-title)

Comment: @adelriosantiago, it is done! I improved the first paragraph. Thanks for your help. I am going to check these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not show a title in your tooltip you will have to only return the value in your custom label calback. So your callback will become this:

```
label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
      return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index].toLocaleString();
    }
```

There is no build in way to get the title in the middle of the circle, you will have to write a custom plugin for that.

To replace the thousand serperator in the percentage label, you will have to write a custom render. So instead `render: 'percentage'`. You will get something like this:

```
// custom render
{
  render: function (args) {
    // args will be something like:
    // { label: 'Label', value: 123, percentage: 50, index: 0, dataset: {...} }
    return '$' + args.value;
  }
}
```

You will have to make the logic so the value gets transformed to a percentage still

EDIT custom tooltip so you dont see the color in front.

```js
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#7792b1';

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var dataset = [{
  label: 'Volume de Operações',
  data: [254000.87, 355000.57],
  backgroundColor: ['#4bb8df', '#6290df']
}]
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['CALL', 'PUT'],
    datasets: dataset
  },

  options: {
    rotation: 1 * Math.PI,
    circumference: 1 * Math.PI,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    cutoutPercentage: 60,
    plugins: {
      labels: [{
        render: 'label',
        arc: true,
        fontStyle: 'bold',
        position: 'outside'
      }, {
        render: 'percentage',
        fontColor: '#ffffff',
        precision: 1
      }],
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      fontSize: 15,
      text: [
        dataset.reduce((t, d) => t + d.data.reduce((a, b) => a + b), 0),
        'Volume Total'
      ],
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false,
      custom: function(tooltipModel) {
        // Tooltip Element
        var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

        // Create element on first render
        if (!tooltipEl) {
          tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
          tooltipEl.id = 'chartjs-tooltip';
          tooltipEl.innerHTML = '<table></table>';
          document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);
        }

        // Hide if no tooltip
        if (tooltipModel.opacity === 0) {
          tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
          return;
        }

        // Set caret Position
        tooltipEl.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
        if (tooltipModel.yAlign) {
          tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltipModel.yAlign);
        } else {
          tooltipEl.classList.add('no-transform');
        }

        function getBody(bodyItem) {
          return bodyItem.lines[0].split(': ')[1].replace('.', ',');
        }

        // Set Text
        if (tooltipModel.body) {
          var titleLines = tooltipModel.title || [];
          var bodyLines = tooltipModel.body.map(getBody);

          var innerHtml = '<thead>';
          innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';

          bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
            var colors = tooltipModel.labelColors[i];
            var style = 'background:' + colors.backgroundColor;
            style += '; border-color:' + colors.borderColor;
            style += '; border-width: 2px';
            var span = '<span style="' + style + '"></span>';
            innerHtml += '<tr><td>' + span + body + '</td></tr>';
          });
          innerHtml += '</tbody>';

          var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
          tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
        }

        // `this` will be the overall tooltip
        var position = this._chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

        // Display, position, and set styles for font
        tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
        tooltipEl.style.position = 'absolute';
        tooltipEl.style.left = position.left + window.pageXOffset + tooltipModel.caretX + 'px';
        tooltipEl.style.top = position.top + window.pageYOffset + tooltipModel.caretY + 'px';
        tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltipModel._bodyFontFamily;
        tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltipModel.bodyFontSize + 'px';
        tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltipModel._bodyFontStyle;
        tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltipModel.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltipModel.xPadding + 'px';
        tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
      }
      /*
        callbacks: {
          label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index].toLocaleString();
          },
          
        }*/
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#chartjs-tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
  transition: all .1s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart" style="max-width: 450px"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels/src/chartjs-plugin-labels.js"></script>
```

You might want to add some dots as thousand seperators in the tooltip but thats up to you. Best place to do it is in the `getBody` method.

Comment: Helped me a lot! But on the tooltip I still have that "colored square" there. Do you know how to remove it?

Comment: Yes by using a custom tooltip, eddited answer with an example for you

Comment: This is it. I just accepted your answer. Thanks!!